# Add Product to Wishlist with a Selected Custom option

Tags: product, magento-1, custom-options, wishlist

I used below code to add a product pragmatically  to a Wishlist, and is working successfully-

```
  $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
  $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

  $customer_id = 1;
  $product_id = 1;
  $customer->load($customer_id);
  $wishlist->loadByCustomer($customer_id);
  $wishlist->addNewItem($product->load($product_id));
```

My Question is that if I am having a Product with a Custom Option, then how could i add that selected option to a wishlist.

Completely, I need a Code which can add Product to a Wishlist with a selected custom option.

Please help me on this.

Comment: I got the solution for above please go through the below Code:<br><br><br> $wishlist=Mage::helper('wishlist')->getWishlist();<br>
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();<br>
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');<br>
$_product = $model->load($productId);<br> 
$params = array('product' => $productId,<br>
  'qty' => 1,<br>
  'store_id' => $storeId,<br>
  'options' => array('optionId'=>'optionValue')<br>
 );<br>
$request = new Varien_Object();<br>
$request->setData($params);<br>
$result = $wishlist->addNewItem($_product, $request);<br>

Answer (score 5):

I got the solution for above please go through the below Code:

```
$wishlist=Mage::helper('wishlist')->getWishlist();
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product = $model->load($productId);
$params = array('product' => $productId,
        'qty' => 1,
        'store_id' => $storeId,
        'options' => array('optionId'=>'optionValue')
    );
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($params);
$result = $wishlist->addNewItem($_product, $request);
```

Comment: This would only work for me if the `options` param was renamed `super_attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file: `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml` and change this line:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, this.href); return false;" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
```

to:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this, this.href); return false;" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
```

I have changed `productAddToCartForm.submitLight` to `productAddToCartForm.submit`

I then made a hidden field to display the error:

```
<div class="validation-advice hidden" id="advice-required-entry-size-select">Please select product size.</div>
```

I added this in file: `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` Add it wherever you want to display the error.

and in the same `configurable.phtml` file i added this small script:

```
$('.link-wishlist').on('click',function(){
   if($('.size-select').val() == ''){
       $('#advice-required-entry-size-select').removeClass('hidden');
     }
    else{
         $('#advice-required-entry-size-select').addClass('hidden');
     }
  });
```

where `.size-select` is a class to my size options.

Comment: Twinkal, can you please tell us will we achieve the task mentioned in the question?

Comment: It did work for me Haris. I don't know your exact requirement, may be its worth a shot.