# Add Configurable Product to Wish List

Tags: wishlist, configurable-swatches, ee-1.14

When a user clicks "Add to Wishlist" on a product that uses swatching, it saves the configurable product ID, **not** the simple product id. How can I get it to save the simple product id in the wish list tables?

[image: Swatches and "Add to Wishlist"]

I have looked at several other questions on Stack Exchange and none of them appear to address this issue:

[Add Product to Wishlist with a Selected Custom option](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31668/add-product-to-wishlist-with-a-selected-custom-option?rq=1)

[Magento 1.6.2 Adding Configurable Product in Wishlist : How to check whether or not all required fields are filled before adding to wishlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680598/magento-1-6-2-adding-configurable-product-in-wishlist-how-to-check-whether-or)

[mangento add product options into wishlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128098/mangento-add-product-options-into-wishlist)

I think most of these solutions are if the options are not set as swatches.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

**Question:** What changes in the code do I need to make in order to save the simple product id to the wish list instead of the configurable product id?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply swatches for configurable products only.

From the docs

> Swatches provide an alternate way to display the selection of options
>   for [configurable products](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable.html). Rather than choosing an option from a
>   drop-down list, customers can make their selection by clicking a
>   swatch

Comment: Thanks for you response, but it does not answer my question, which is "How can I get it to save the simple product id in the wish list tables?"

Comment: Yes i got it but You cannot do it until you do some changes in core.

Comment: I understand I need to make changes to the core, I'm hoping someone can provide me guidance on what needs to change in the core in order to add configurable products to the wish list.